# SQL Server CONCAT adds blank spaces when used

Tags: sql-server, concatenation

I've tried to use CONCAT function of some fields in a table; in order to get a string that I need to compare onto another field from different table.

However when I use the function it's like it random adds spaces between the fields and then I cannot use this result to compare.

I've tried:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT([STC_GL-STC].[ZZGL_Desc_Group_5D],'-',
              [STC_GL-STC].[ZZCostCentreGroup],'-',
              AS RESULT
FROM [STC_GL-STC];
```

As an example of result:

```
'Compras - RM -MATERIA PRIMA -'
```

(Please note the blank spaces in the second and third (-).

I would need to obtain:

```
'Compras - RM-MATERIA PRIMA-'
```

I've checked the values in the fields and there is no blank spaces at the end on fields ZZGL_Desc_Group_5D , ZZCostCentreGroup.

I've also tried:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-',[ZZGL_Desc_Group_5D],[ZZCostCentreGroup]) AS RESULT
FROM [STC_GL-STC]
```

With same result.

And finally I tried to remove blank spaces using RTRIM and LTRIM using the following:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM([STC_GL-STC].[ZZGL_Desc_Group_5D])),
              LTRIM(RTRIM('-')),
              LTRIM(RTRIM([STC_GL-STC].[ZZCostCentreGroup]))) AS RESULT
FROM [STC_GL-STC]
ORDER BY RESULT ASC;
```

And even with LTRIM and RTRIM functions on that field, I still getting the same result.

How to get rid of this behaviour and of the blank spaces? Is there another way to build that string?

Kind Regards and many thanks in advance,

Comment: `CONCAT` isn't doing this. Your data clearly has leading or trailing spaces, or some other (non-printable) character.

Comment: If trimming does not remove the space, then you don't have an actual "space" character. Find a row where this occurs and cast one of these "space-like" columns to varbinary to see the actual ascii/unicode value. And then go fix your data and the process that adds or modifies the rows.

Comment: I would suggest trying to produce a [mre] (MRE), as I don't doubt that your attempt to do so will tell you what those characters are. This is why posting a MRE is so important, as half the time you find the reason when you attempt to create said MRE.

Comment: Curious to see an MRE as well, though more importantly, if the table which you're comparing to has these as separate fields, you're killing performance by comparing a concatenated string; you'd much rather compare on 5 individual columns. Putting this out there just in case, as I've seen someone do this in the past.

Comment: I've tried to edit my initial post to an MRE and its behaviour.

Comment: I don't see *any* sample data, or [mre] in your question at all, @1987kess . There's no SQL we can run to reproduce the problem. A MRE, for a sQL based question, would contain DDL for the objects, `INSERT` statements for the data, and then the problem statement that reproduces the undesired behaviour/error.

Comment: The `TRIM` functions only remove spaces. Not any other kind of invisible characters, even if they'd classify as whitespace. Try `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), ...)` to check for other invisible characters.

Comment: See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=312fa6ea235554d2d7f4a55c35d1984c) as an example, which **does not** reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry to not include an MRE. The population of data in the table is done via SSIS and I could not reproduce that part.

However converting that data to binary I've found that there were carriage returns at the end of some lines, so there is the issue and that really helped me. I will communicate to the data source vendor this issue in order to see if it's possible to populate the data withouth these.

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago I created a udf function to remove white spaces.

It is based on the 'magic' of the XML `xs:token` data type.

**udf**

```
/*
1. All invisible TAB, Carriage Return, and Line Feed characters will be replaced with spaces.
2. Then leading and trailing spaces are removed from the value. 
3. Further, contiguous occurrences of more than one space will be replaced with a single space.
*/
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_tokenize(@input VARCHAR(MAX))
   RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN 
   RETURN (SELECT CAST('<r><![CDATA[' + @input + ']]></r>' AS XML).value('(/r/text())[1] cast as xs:token?','VARCHAR(MAX)'));
END
```

**Test harness**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @mockTbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), col_1 VARCHAR(100), col_2 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockTbl (col_1, col_2)
VALUES ('  FL   ', '  Miami')
   , ('  FL   ', '  Fort       Lauderdale   ')
   , ('  NY   ', '  New           York   ')
   , ('  NY   ', '')
   , ('  NY   ', NULL);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT * 
    , col_1n = dbo.udf_tokenize(col_1)
    , col_2n = dbo.udf_tokenize(col_2)
    , CONCAT_WS('-', dbo.udf_tokenize(col_1), dbo.udf_tokenize(col_2)) AS RESULT
FROM @mockTbl;
```